# How to put signature to an existing pdf using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdflib, signaturepad

I've been working on placing a signature in a specific location within a PDF, such as next to the word 'Signature' at the top. If I want to achieve this, how can I do it using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or any frameworks like React or Svelte?

We have a PDF with forms that may or may not be filled. The PDF includes a designated area for the signature, and we need to insert the signature accordingly. This is the task I need to accomplish. How can I do it?

thank you.

i tried some libraries like signature-pad to create signature. but couldn't put it to existing pdf. but with the help of JSPDF i could create a pdf. which is not i want.

Comment: Are you talking about a digital signature, or it is just that you want to stamp a picture of a signature over a page? If it's the latter, you can do this with https://github.com/coherentgraphics/coherentpdf.js/ (disclaimer, which I wrote). It's pure JavaScript, and the function you need is stampOver which can stamp one PDF (the signature) over another.